# How to make the virtual-scroll with "OnDemandGrid" efficiently

Tags: javascript, dgrid, dojo

I am creating a dgrid OnDemandGrid. The store is a dojo/store/MemoryStore which has a JSON datasets close to 50k records.
I am using this store in my OnDemandGrid. When I start scrolling, my script hangs & chrome throws a msg dialog saying the page is unresponsive and would you like to kill it.

I am not getting how to make the scrolling efficient and effective without my page dying.
Below is the code for the grid.

```
request("../../data/dataInJsonFormat.json", {
            handleAs: "json"
        }).then(function(response) {
            var store = new Memory({
                data: response
            });
            var grid = new OnDemandGrid({
                id: "DataRecords",
                // minRowsPerPage: 10,
                // maxRowsPerPage: 10,
                // bufferRows: 20,
                // pagingMethod: "throttleDelayed",
                keepScrollPosition: true,
                loadingMessage: "Loading Data",
                store: store,
                columns: {
                    COMPNOS: "COMPNOS",
                    NatureCode: "NatureCode",
                    SHIFT: "Day"
                }
            }, "dataGrid");
            grid.startup();
```

The doc, says that OnDemandGrid will take care of virtual scrolling but it seems to be crashing for this data set. Is this dataset too big ? Do I need to use another kind of store?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

50,000 records is a *lot* of records for an in-memory store.  Even though dgrid will lazily render the data as the user scrolls, the Memory store will be forced to find and copy a tiny slice out of that huge array every time scrolling occurs.  While 50k records doesn't make Chrome hang for me, it does make each query noticeably slower.

Moreover, by requesting all of that data and storing it in-memory, you're requiring your users to download all 50k records, while they might only ever look at 1% of them.  Generally in-memory stores are only advisable up to a few thousand results at most.  You probably ought to look at a server-based store such as dojo/store/JsonRest (assuming you have or can build a [service which behaves as it expects](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/rest.html)), or [dojo-smore/QueryRead](https://github.com/kfranqueiro/dojo-smore/blob/master/QueryRead.js) (a `dojo/store` implementation similar to [dojox/data/QueryReadStore](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/data/QueryReadStore.html)).  These will only fire requests to the server for records that the user actually scrolls to.